Mounted partition not visible in dock and files but showing in terminal
I'm using dual boot and The mounted partition used to be in the dock and other locations in files, I use it very often to access the files from the windows partition but currently not showing in both dock and files. I unmounted and mounted it back in terminal but not accessible via files. But it's accessible through terminal:

Help me to resolve this

The partition is accessible via files but you'd need to explicitely browse to the mount-point, in your case this is the /mnt-directory.
To make the partition visible on your dock or as a partition in your filemanager you need to mount the partition in a subdirectrory of /media, for example /media/mydrive.
You may need to create that directory first, e.g sudo mkdir /media/mydrive.
